# How do I implement this determinant solver code recursively?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have created code that solves determinants up to 6x6, but the self 
similarity of this problem makes it seem like it would be well suited to a 
recursive method. I also would like to make the code able to solve larger 
matrices than just 6x6.

I have little experience with recursive functions, so I am not sure 
where to start. I have looked at some tutorials online but most are just 
about the Fibonacci sequence or some other simple example. Resources would 
be appreciated. Warning: the code is pretty long.

```
    function determinant(m) {
      var sum = 0;
      console.log(m);
      if(m.length==1){
        return m[0][0];
      }
      if(m.length==2){
         return twoByTwo(m);
      }
      if(m.length==3){
        return threeByThree(m);
      }
      if(m.length==4){
        return fourByFour(m);
      }
      if(m.length==5){
        return fiveByFive(m);
      }
      if(m.length==6){
        return sixBySix(m);
      }
    }

    ...//5x5 and 6x6 fxns

    //4x4 det fxn
    function fourByFour(m){
      var sum = 0;
      var matrix = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(m));
      m.shift();
      m[0].shift();
      m[1].shift();
      m[2].shift();
      sum+=(matrix[0][0])*threeByThree(m);
      m = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(matrix));
      m.shift();
      m[0].splice(1,1);
      m[1].splice(1,1);
      m[2].splice(1,1);
      sum-=(matrix[0][1])*threeByThree(m);
      m = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(matrix));
      m.shift();
      m[0].splice(2,1);
      m[1].splice(2,1);
      m[2].splice(2,1);
      sum+=(matrix[0][2])*threeByThree(m);
      m = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(matrix));
      m.shift();
      m[0].pop();
      m[1].pop();
      m[2].pop();
      sum-=(matrix[0][3])*threeByThree(m);
      return sum;
    }
    //3x3 det fxn
    function threeByThree(m){
      var sum = 0;
      var matrix = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(m));
      m.shift();
      m[0].shift();
      m[1].shift();
      sum+=(matrix[0][0])*twoByTwo(m);
      m = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(matrix));
      m.shift();
      m[0].splice(1,1);
      m[1].splice(1,1);
      sum-=(matrix[0][1])*twoByTwo(m);
      m = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(matrix));
      m.shift();
      m[0].pop();
      m[1].pop();
      sum+=(matrix[0][2])*twoByTwo(m);
      return sum;
    }
    //2x2 det fxn
    function twoByTwo(m){
      return ((m[0][0])*(m[1][1])-(m[0][1])*(m[1][0]));
    }
```

The results for this function are accurate, but only work on matrices up to 6x6, I would like to generalize the function to take any size matrix. I imagine that a similar method to what I am currently doing could be implemented recursively and then the function would be able to solve the determinant of even larger matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Going by the "[minor expansion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant)" mentioned in Wikipedia, you can calculate the determinant recursively by calculating determinants of the minor matrices as you iterate through each index in the first row of your original matrix.

You can see an implementation below:

```js
function determinant(m) {
  const subMatrix = (index) => m.slice(1).map(row => row.filter((e, colIndex) => colIndex !== index));
  const sign = (index) => index % 2 === 0 ? 1 : -1;

  if (m.length === 1) return m[0][0];
  return m[0].reduce((sum, curr, i) => sum + sign(i) * curr * determinant(subMatrix(i)), 0);
}

const matrix = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 15, 6],
  [7, 8, 19]
];

console.log(determinant(matrix));
```